# Angular throw error $parse: ueoe Unexpected End of Expression

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs, node.js

This part of my site is with an error and i can't figure out, since i didn't change that in months.

The error is:

```
Error: [$parse:ueoe] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$parse/ueoe?p0=event._id%3FEventController
    at Error (native)
    at http://localhost:3000/scripts/libs.js:44598:416
    at Object.q.consume (http://localhost:3000/scripts/libs.js:44801:157)
    at Object.q.ternary (http://localhost:3000/scripts/libs.js:44794:497)
    at Object.q.assignment (http://localhost:3000/scripts/libs.js:44794:284)
    at Object.q.expression (http://localhost:3000/scripts/libs.js:44794:237)
    at Object.q.filterChain (http://localhost:3000/scripts/libs.js:44794:145)
    at Object.q.expressionStatement (http://localhost:3000/scripts/libs.js:44794:91)
    at Object.q.program (http://localhost:3000/scripts/libs.js:44793:458)
    at Object.q.ast (http://localhost:3000/scripts/libs.js:44793:257) <li class="controller__item controller__item--disabled" data-controller-range="[1, 1]" data-event-sidebar-to="false" ng-click="event._id ? EventController.update(event._id, event) : EventController.create(event)">
```

According to angular.js:

Error: $parse:ueoe
Unexpected End of Expression
Unexpected end of expression: event._id
Description
Occurs when an expression is missing tokens at the end of the expression. For example, forgetting a closing bracket in an expression will trigger this error.

To resolve, learn more about Angular expressions, identify the error and fix the expression's syntax.

The HTML template:

```
<main class="main">
    <div ng-include src="'/admin/navbar/navbar.template.html'"></div>
    <div ng-include src="'/admin/breadcrumb/breadcrumb.template.html'"></div>
    <section class="events">
        <div class="events__container">
            <div class="events__row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="events__box">
                        <div class="events__header">
                            <h2 class="events__title"> Todos os eventos - </h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="events__body">
                            <table class="events__table" data-table>
                                <!-- directive:table-sorter-directive -->
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th class="events__th events__th--all">
                                            <input type="checkbox" />
                                        </th>
                                        <th class="events__th"> Nome </th>
                                        <th class="events__th"> Data </th>
                                        <th class="events__th events__th--reservations"> Reservas </th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr class="events__tr" ng-repeat="event in events">
                                        <td class="events__td events__td--checkbox">
                                            <input type="checkbox" data-controller-input ng-click="EventController.retrieveOne(event._id)"/>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="events__td"> {{ event.name }} </td>
                                        <td class="events__td"> {{ event.date }} </td>
                                        <td class="events__td events__td--reservations"> 50 </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <aside class="events__sidebar" data-event-sidebar>
                <!-- directive:event-sidebar-directive  -->
                <form class="events__sidebar-form" method="POST" action="#">
                    <div class="events__sidebar-group">
                        <label class="events__sidebar-label" for="event_value"> Valores: </label>
                        <input class="events__sidebar-input event__sidebar-input--value" type="text" id="event_value" ng-model="event.men"/>
                        <input class="events__sidebar-input event__sidebar-input--value" type="text" id="event_value" ng-model="event.women"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="events__sidebar-group">
                        <label class="events__sidebar-label" for="event_name"> Nome do evento: </label>
                        <input class="events__sidebar-input" type="text" id="event_name" ng-model="event.name"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="events__sidebar-group">
                        <label class="events__sidebar-label" for="event_hour"> Hora: </label>
                        <input class="events__sidebar-input" type="text" id="event_hour" ng-model="event.hour"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="events__sidebar-group">
                        <label class="events__sidebar-label" for="event_point"> Ponto de encontro: </label>
                        <input class="events__sidebar-input" type="text" id="event_point" ng-model="event.meeting"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="events__sidebar-group">
                        <label class="events__sidebar-label" for="event_info"> Informações simples: </label>
                        <input class="events__sidebar-input" type="text" id="event_info" placeholder="1 Hora de Open Bar + 2 horas de loucura"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="events__sidebar-group">
                        <label class="events__sidebar-label" for="event_hiw"> Como funciona: </label>
                        <input class="events__sidebar-input" type="text" id="event_hiw" ng-model="event.hiw"/>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </aside>
        </div>
    </section>
    <aside class="controller" data-controller> 
        <!-- directive:controller-directive -->
        <!-- directive:controller-action-directive  -->
        <div class="controller__controller" data-controller-indicator>
            <i class="icon icon__cogs"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="controller__container">
            <ul class="controller__list">
                <li class="controller__item"                            data-controller-range="[0]" data-event-sidebar-to="true" ng-click="EventController.clean()">
                    <i    class="icon icon__plus icon__2x"></i>
                    <span class="controller__legend"> Novo </span>
                </li>
                <li class="controller__item controller__item--disabled" data-controller-range="[1, 1]" data-event-sidebar-to="true">
                    <i    class="icon icon__pencil icon__2x"></i>
                    <span class="controller__legend"> Editar </span>
                </li>
                <li class="controller__item controller__item--disabled" data-controller-range="[1, 1]" data-event-sidebar-to="false" ng-click="event._id ? EventController.update(event._id, event) : EventController.create(event)">
                    <i    class="icon icon__cloud icon__2x"></i>
                    <span class="controller__legend"> Salvar </span>
                </li>
                <li class="controller__item controller__item--disabled" data-controller-range="[1]" data-event-sidebar-to="false" ng-click="EventController.delete(event._id)">
                    <i    class="icon icon__trash icon__2x"></i>
                    <span class="controller__legend"> Deletar </span>
                </li>
                <li class="controller__item controller__item--email">
                    <i    class="icon icon__search icon__2x"></i>
                    <span class="controller__legend"> E-mail </span>
                </li>
                <li class="controller__item controller__item--search">
                    <i    class="icon icon__envelope icon__2x"></i>
                    <span class="controller__legend"> Pesquisar </span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </aside>
</main>
```

EventController.js:

```
'use strict';
var EventController = function(scope, EventModel) {
    this.scope      = scope;
    this.EventModel = EventModel;
    this.scope.store = [];

    this.retrieve();
};

EventController.prototype = {
    clean: function() {
        this.scope.event = {};
    },

    create: function(newEvent) {
        this.EventModel.Model.insert(newEvent)
            .then(function(result) {

            });
    },

    retrieve: function() {
        var that = this;

        this.EventModel.Model.find()
            .then(function(result) {
                that.scope.events = result;
            });
    },

    retrieveOne: function(eventId) {
        var that = this;

        this.EventModel.Model.findOne(eventId)
            .then(function(result) {
                that.scope.event = result;
            });
    },

    update: function(editedEvent, event) {
        this.EventModel.Model.update(editedEvent, event)
            .then(function(result) {

            });
    },

    delete: function(eventId) {
        this.EventModel.Model.remove(eventId)
            .then(function(result) {

            });
    }
};

angular.module('adminApp').controller('EventController', ['$scope', 'EventModel', EventController]);
```

I can't figure out what is the problem. Anybody can help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the error might be cause of the `src` attribute

```
ng-include src="'/admin/navbar/navbar.template.html'"
ng-include src="'/admin/breadcrumb/breadcrumb.template.html'"
```

should be

```
ng-include="'/admin/navbar/navbar.template.html'"
ng-include="'/admin/breadcrumb/breadcrumb.template.html'"
```

`src` should be the attribute only when included as an `element`  `<ng-include`

But in you case the `ng-include` is used as an `attribute`

For more info check the docs **[ng-include](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude)**

Comment: nothing.. i believe this error is being cause because of                 <li class="controller__item controller__item--disabled" data-controller-range="[1, 1]" data-event-sidebar-to="false" ng-click="event._id ? EventController.update(event._id, event) : EventController.create(event)"> if i take off the error will disappear

Comment: but i cant just take it off.. doesn't make much sense, until yesterday it was working just fine.

Comment: but i cant just take it off.. doesn't make much sense, until yesterday it was working just fine.

Comment: Also does `event` refer to the event object ? If that is true, should it not be `$event`

Answer (score -1):

**hide this code in ng-grid.js - it add extra column when group is add.**

Moved out of above loops due to if no data initially, but has initial grouping, columns won't be added

```
    if(cols.length > 0) {
        for (var z = 0; z < groups.length; z++) {
            if (!cols[z].isAggCol && z <= maxDepth) {
                cols.push(new ngColumn({
                    colDef: {
                        field: '',
                        width: 25,
                        sortable: false,
                        resizable: false,
                        headerCellTemplate: '<div class="ngAggHeader"></div>',
                        pinned: grid.config.pinSelectionCheckbox

                    },
                    enablePinning: grid.config.enablePinning,
                    isAggCol: true,
                    headerRowHeight: grid.config.headerRowHeight

                }, $scope, grid, domUtilityService, $templateCache, $utils));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's not an answer for the initial question. You've provided answer for this bug: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/issues/3693 (which actually helped me lol)