# Getting Error: [$parse:ueoe] using Angular.js and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I am getting the following error while declaring `ng-class` inside li tag in my php file.

```
angularjs.js:107Error: [$parse:ueoe] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.6/$parse/ueoe?p0=%7B
    at Error (native)
    at http://oditek.in/crm/js/angularjs.js:6:416
    at Object.s.peekToken (http://oditek.in/crm/js/angularjs.js:209:514)
    at Object.s.object (http://oditek.in/crm/js/angularjs.js:208:336)
    at Object.s.primary (http://oditek.in/crm/js/angularjs.js:205:503)
    at Object.s.unary (http://oditek.in/crm/js/angularjs.js:205:342)
    at Object.s.multiplicative (http://oditek.in/crm/js/angularjs.js:205:88)
    at Object.s.additive (http://oditek.in/crm/js/angularjs.js:204:430)
    at Object.s.relational (http://oditek.in/crm/js/angularjs.js:204:265)
    at Object.s.equality (http://oditek.in/crm/js/angularjs.js:204:90) <a href="product.php#/dashboard" ng-class="{" active":="" $state.includes("dashboard")}"="">
```

I am explaining my code below.

```
<?php
if(in_array("Info",$userrights)){
            //$class=(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'product.php') || strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'product.php'))?'class="active"':'';
            echo'<li><a href="product.php#/dashboard" ng-class="{"active": $state.includes("dashboard")}">E-Vouchers<b class="caret"></b></a>';
        }
?>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="dashboard">Dashboard</a></li>
  <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="code">Generate Voucher Code</a></li>
 <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="list">E-Voucher List</a></li>
   </ul>
 </li>
```

Here my requirement is when user will click on any sub menu present in the above code ,the parent menu(`i.e-E-Vouchers`) will get also active class along with the sub menu.Please help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular throw error $parse: ueoe Unexpected End of Expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32084562/angular-throw-error-parse-ueoe-unexpected-end-of-expression)